# number of slaves running jobs on hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop cluster with 1 master and 20 slaves, checked that all the datanode and tasktracker daemons have been already started and working normally on each slave machine. Now I want to use only 5 of the slaves to run my mapreduce jobs, could I simply specify this 5 slave machines in file conf/slaves and hadoop will automatically run jobs only on this 5 machines? And Should I restart any daemons for this change of slave numbers to take effect(mapred for example)?

Thanks!
Dong

Comment: Hi Dong

I'm not able to understand why you have 20 datanodes and want to "use only 5 ... to run mapreduce jobs"

Comment: Hi, Nishant, it's because I have set up a hadoop cluster with 20 slaves, now I want to compare the performance of a program under different number of working slaves, but I do not want to kill the daemons of datanode and tasktracker on those slave nodes that will not run mapreduce tasks. So maybe a better way is e.g, to just supply the desired slave nodes in the conf/slaves so that only these nodes will run jobs...